# How can I set the delivery date to a time period in Konik's ZUGFeRD library?

Tags: java, java.util.date

I use [Konik's Java library](http://konik.io/docs/index.html) for creating electronic invoices in [ZUGFeRD format](http://www.pdflib.com/knowledge-base/pdfa/zugferd-invoices/). I would like to set the delivery date to a period of time (e.g. "Q3 2016"). Ideally, I would like to use a custom string for the representation of this date.

The library requires passing a `ZfDate` object when instantiating a `Delivery` object as part of my invoice. Since `ZfDate` (and its subclasses) are based on `java.util.Date` I don't see how to deal with periods of time or custom strings in this context at all.

Is this a limitation of this library or of the ZUGFeRD specification in general? Is there a workaround maybe?

As far as I know, using periods of time in (paper-based) invoices is fine from a legal point of view (in Germany), so it would be nice to have support for this feature in the electronic format as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the Type Hierarchy of
ZfDate you will see 3 sub types.

[image: Type Hierarchy of ZfDate]

Those 3 types also represent the current possibilities that are allowed in ZUGFeRD.

- Day with Code `102` with string `yyyyMMdd`.
- Month of the year as Code `610` with string `yyyyMM`.
- Week of the year as Code `616` with string `yyyyww`.

Keep in mind that having fancy dates like 'July to December 2016' in you ZUGFeRD invoice will make it difficult or impossible for other parties to automatically process the invoices. If possible keep it simple. Also don't forget that you can put this type of information on the visual representation of the invoice (pdf only part) as in most cases this information is solely intended for humans.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Vadimo. I can see why a ZUGFeRD invoice cannot support custom text as dates. Having support for date periods defined by two instants would be nice to have, but I can live with the current solution.

Answer (score 3):

A `java.util.Date` represents an instant in time, so you can't represent a period (a range of instants) with one.

Three obvious options you have are the first, middle or last instants of the period as "the" instant to use.

Comment: Thank you. This clearly means the ZfDate classes do not support my use case. The questions remains if there are other ways to realise my use case within the specification in general and with the library specifically.

Comment: Exact, the delivery data is specified as an fixed point in time and can't be by Definition a period.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I am *not* familiar with the Konik library, ZUGFeRD, or its underlying specifications. But I am curious and poked around a bit.

## `Zf…` classes

Yes, [`ZfDate`](http://konik.io/docs/api/konik/io/konik/zugferd/unqualified/ZfDate.html) extends the [`java.util.Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class. `ZfDate` in turn is extended into 3 other `Zf…` classes.

As the [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38296341/642706) by Bohemian said, this means you cannot store a date range as that data types represents a single moment on the timeline. However read on for the “Invoice period” I found.

## java.time

That inheritance from `java.util.Date` is unfortunate, as the old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are now legacy. They have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The java.time classes include replacements for `java.util.Date`, [`java.time.Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), as well as at least 1 of the 3 other `Zf…` classes, [`java.time.YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html). The [`ThreeTen-Extra`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project that extends java.time includes classes for [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), and more, FYI.

## Invoice data model

Following your links, it is not easy to pin down the exact full specification. But links to links took me to:

[Guide for a European CORE INVOICE data model with UN/CEFACT CII Implementation Guideline - Part 2: European CORE INVOICE data model](http://www.cen.eu/work/areas/ICT/eBusiness/Documents/CWA%2016356-2.pdf)

### Invoice period

Look for `Rq024`. In a table on page 15, find a definition for “Invoice period information”.

> For invoices that charge for services or items delivered over a time period, such as subscriptions or metered services, a Core Invoice may contain information about the date period to which the invoice applies.

As part of that period, it defines a pair of dates, “Invoice period start date” and “Invoice period end date”. Unfortunately I cannot find any definition of a “date”. I also did not notice any provision for a span of time other than this pair of dates, but I only performed a quick perusal.

## ISO 8601

If you resort to Strings as notations in the invoice, take a look at the ISO 8601 standard for formats of strings representing various date-time values. ISO standards are not freely available, so either purchase a copy or study the synopsis in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

The standard defines a week-of-year and provides notation such as `2016-W27` for one particular week, and `2016-W27-7` for a particular day in that week.

For a start/end pair, use a slash as a separator. For example: “2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/2008-05-11T15:30:00Z”.

For a span of time not tied to the timeline, use `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. For example, `P3M` for three months.

Unfortunately, the standard does not provide for quarters. Some people informally employ the style of ISO 8601 with a `Q` literal such as `2016-Q1`.

Comment: Thank your for all the efforts you put in answering my question. I found your answer really informative although I do not see any immediate solution for my problem, unfortunately. The Konik library does not support the new jave.time framework and does not allow me to specify ISO 8601 strings for the delivery date, as far as I can see. It's good to know the CORE INVOICE data model support date periods, though.